# Unit Testing AngularJS and PouchDB Service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-service, angular-mock

I am attempting to unit test my individual Angular factories but am having a hard time trying to correctly mock and inject the PouchDB object.  My factory code is currently as follows:

```
factory('Track', [function() {
    var db = new PouchDB('tracks');
    var resource = {
        getAll: function() {
          return db.allDocs({include_docs: true});
        }
    return resource;
}]);
```

I had tried to use Angular's $provide service to inject a mock PouchDB instance with no luck:

```
 module(function($provide) {
    $provide.value('PouchDB', {
        allDocs: function() {
            return 'MOCKED';
        }
    });
```

I am not entirely sure where to go from here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why exactly is it not working? It throws an exception? Also: Where is the `PouchDB`-Service common from? Since you dont seem to inject it inside your factory, I guess its just a global variable outside the Angular-Scope?

Comment: I cannot get the PouchDB object to be mockable within my tests.  The PouchDB var comes from the inclusion of the pouchDB javascript library file which yes must make it a global variable outside of the angular scope.  Do I/Should I need to refactor the global inclusion of PouchDB library into an Angularized service and inject that into my factories?

Comment: Yep, thats the way to go. Since Angular handles DI via just using parameters inside functions, you would need to pass the to-be-mocked-object also as a parameter - meaning wrap it in a service or factory. Im gonna post this as an answer, too.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for making me think through it =] I didn't think about moving it into a service until you mentioned being a global var and then thinking to myself "that certainly isn't the Angular way"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As just stated in the comments:
you have to wrap the global variable `PouchDB` inside a service to make it injectable. This is due to Angular doing DI via simple function-parameters. So just do something like:

```
  angular.module('myModule')
     .factory('PouchDBWrapper', function(){
         return PouchDB;
     }
```

Then you can inject it into your Track factory:

```
 factory('Track', [function(PouchDBWrapper) {
   var db = new PouchDBWrapper('tracks');
   var resource = {
      getAll: function() {
         return db.allDocs({include_docs: true});
      }
    return resource;
}]);
```

and in your test you can mock it by:

```
module(function($provide) {
   $provide.factory('PouchDBWrapper', {
       allDocs: function() {
           return 'MOCKED';
       }
});
```