# How to write unit and/or integration tests for an angular app that uses PouchDB

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, integration-testing, karma-jasmine, pouchdb

I am working with a large AngularJS + PouchDB codebase. We are using Protractor for end-to-end testing, but we found ourselves relying too much on end-to-end tests. These are slow and often fail intermittently.

We would like to migrate as much of our testing to unit tests and/or integration tests. We have a working karma-jasmine setup that we use to test some code that doesn't interact with the database. We would like to use Karma to test code that does interact with the database but are not sure of the best way to do this.

Here is one example:

```
"use strict";

var FooService;

describe('The FooService', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.module('myApp');
  });

  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (_FooService_) {
     FooService = _FooService_;
  }));

  it('should be able to return all bars', function() {
    let bars = FooService.getBars();
  });
});
```

This fails because the `FooService.getBars()` method calls PouchDB which has not been initialized.

Do you have a similar codebase and use unit and/or integration testing? If so, how did you address this problem?

Comment: Same way as with any third-party API. Mock it. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591994/unit-testing-angularjs-and-pouchdb-service

Comment: For a proper unit test: mock. For integration tests, you can easily initialize pouchdb, and run it with a local (i.e. filesystem-backed) database for tests.

Comment: Thanks @Flimzy. I am aware of mocking for unit tests but I am mainly interested in integration testing. I have initialized pouchdb but am not sure how to use the promises that it returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing integration tests for PouchDB is totally possible but requires a few things to get it working correctly. One is that you need to make sure that you can successfully connect to your PouchDB server from within the running karma process, and the rest are captured by this sample code.

```
it('should be able to successfully make a PouchDB request', (done) => {
  jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;
  let interval = 20;

  let timeoutId = setInterval(() => {
    $rootScope.$digest();
  }, interval);

  let promise = MyService.methodThatCallsPouchDB();

  result.then((results) => {
    // expectations
  }).finally(done);
});
```

If you are unable to connect to your CouchDB server from code running within karma, you may need to run [add-cors-to-couchdb](https://github.com/pouchdb/add-cors-to-couchdb) as well as add support for the non-standard x-pouchdb request header. Note that the below is for a simple single-node CouchDB configuration suitable for development purposes.

```
# Configure CouchDB to enable CORS
# If add-cors-to-couchdb is missing, install with npm install -g add-cors-to-couchdb
add-cors-to-couchdb http://localhost:5984 -u myAdminUser -p myAdminPassword

# Add non-standard x-pouchdb header not added by add-cors-to-couchdb
curl 'http://myAdminUser:myAdminPassword@localhost:5984/_node/nonode@nohost/_config/cors/headers' \
-X PUT \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-binary '"accept, authorization, content-type, origin, referer, x-csrf-token, x-pouchdb"'
```